# Can you please explain what "Not to say" means here:

Tags: meaning

Can you please explain what "Not to say" means in the context of the following sentence.  "Not to say I might not be up for going tomorrow".

Comment: It's a conversational idiom that means, roughly, "Don't take what I just said, or any other signal you might have noticed, to mean that I don't want to go tomorrow; in fact, I might well like it, but I'm waiting for ... to decide."

Answer (score 3):

There's supposed to be a "that's" before "not to say," but people often omit it.

**That's not to say (that)**

> used for adding a statement that corrects what you have just said or makes it less definite

[- Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/that-s-not-to-say-that)

This is used to disambiguate a sentence that may imply something that you don't mean to imply.  Suppose I ask someone to go see a movie with me today, and they say no.  I could easily infer from their reply that they don't want to see that movie at all, or that they don't want to see a movie with me specifically.  If the person turning me down anticipates these false inferences, they may preempt them by saying something like, "I don't want to see a movie with you tonight, but that's not to say that I don't want to spend time with you," or something equivalent.

If you google this saying, you'll run into some difficulty because there's another, opposite meaning for the phrase "Not to say."

**Not to say**

> used to introduce a stronger alternative or addition to something already said.
>    - Google

It's my uneducated suspicion that this is a corruption of "to say nothing of" which is a way of pointing out a fact that complements the point that you're making (similar to "it goes without saying" or "not to mention").  Then again, I'm an American English speaker, and "not to say" is a British thing, so I may be completely off base.

Answer (score 0):

It just means something like "That does not mean..."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: "Not to say I might not be up for going tomorrow" is roughly equivalent with in meaning with "That does not mean I might not be up for going tomorrow" So I think my comment does provide an answer to the question. For a non-native speaker the phrase "That does not mean..." might be easier to understand than "(That's) not to say..." which I feel can be a rather confusing turn of phrase.

Comment: It might be easier, but it might not. Proper explanations as to how it works are more helpful than rewriting without a sound reason.